# Is there an metric equivalent to the NEMA step motor frame sizes?

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, mount

I just took the axis motors of my EMCO F1P CNC mill and measured them to figure out which frame size they have.

The square flange is exactly `60 x 60 mm`, and the distance between mounting holes is exactly `50 x 50 mm`. This rules out any **NEMA** frame size.

I want to replace the motors, so my question is, is there a similar standard for electrical motors to NEMA that is based in metric units (European/German perhaps), or do I have to make adapter plates to fit NEMA motors?

Comment: Motors can be re-manufactured - unless it was crushed under a tank, but re-winding is usually cost effective.

Comment: Well actually I want to replace them because I can't find drivers for them! They are 10-wire 5-phase step motors which is awesome until you want a driver.

Comment: If you can get a shaft about 1/4" longer than otherwise needed you can readily machine an adapter plate that thickness, though you might need to rotate the motor 45 degree for clearance.  Are you sure you measured the *center* distance of the holes?   NEMA 23 and 24 are both quite close to your quoted size.  At an extreme, I once machined a new front piece for a surplus stepper, though beware that disassembly introduces many issues.

Answer (score 0):

Igus makes 60mm flange stepper motors.

The tech spec download is what i checked but i didn't pull a cad file on the size you're talking about.
https://www.igus.com/product/1262?artNr=MOT-AN-S-060-059-086-M-D-AAAD

Comment: Can you make this an answer that won't go down with the link?